# What's the idiomatic way to take top n values according to some criteria?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have the following code:

```
Sighting.all
      .iterator
      .map(s => (s, haversineDistance(s, ourLocation)))
      .toSeq
      .sortBy(_._2)
      .take(5)
```

As expected, it returns 5 sightings closests to `ourLocation`.

However, for a very large number of sightings, it does not scale well. We can instead just go through all sightings O(N) and find the 5 closest ones, instead of sorting them all and thus doing O(N*logN). How to do so idiomatically?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search

Comment: It depends on how often you do the query with the same pointset and different locations.

Answer (score 2):

As with your previous questions, `fold` might be of use. In this case I'd be tempted to fold over a `PriorityQueue` initialized to values larger than the expected data set.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue

...
.iterator
.foldLeft(PriorityQueue((999,"x"),(999,"x"),(999,"x"),(999,"x"),(999,"x")){
  case (pq, s) => pq.+=((haversineDistance(s, ourLocation), s)).tail
}
```

The result is a `PriorityQueue` of 5 (distance, sighting) tuples, but only the 5 smallest distances.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. To me, `fold` does not feel intuitive. Does it to you?

Comment: If you use a tool often enough it starts to feel like 2nd nature. `fold` is a pretty useful tool to have around.

Comment: Why mutate priority queues instead of using a `SortedSet`?

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov; Good point. One advantage of the `PriorityQueue` is that if you add one and subtract one you'll always have the same size queue, even if you have duplicate data elements. No so with `SortedSet`. Trying to add a duplicate and then removing the element with the largest value will shrink the size of the result set.

Comment: @jwvh that's true, but you can just check collection's size (then you also don't have to pick stub values)

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov; It still depends on how you want duplicate data represented in your results, but I see your point. Instead of testing the Set size before dropping the largest element, you could just `.take(5)` at each iteration. I like it.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid sorting the big list by iterating through each of the elements in the list just once while maintaining a 5-element list as follows:

1. Keep the 5-element list sorted by distance in descending order so that its head element has the longest distance (Note that since 5 is small the cost of sorting is negligible)
2. In each iteration, if the current element in the original list has its distance shorter than that of the head element in the 5-element list, replace the head element with the current element; otherwise keep the current 5-element list

Upon completing the iterations, the 5-element list will consist of elements with the shortest distances and a final sorting by distance in ascending order will give the top5 list:

```
val list = Sighting.all.
  iterator.
  map(s => (s, haversineDistance(s, ourLocation))).
  toSeq

// For example ...
res1: list = List(
  ("a", 5), ("b", 2), ("c", 12), ("d", 9), ("e", 6), ("f", 15),
  ("g", 9), ("h", 7), ("i", 6), ("j", 3), ("k", 10), ("l", 5)
)

val top5 = list.drop(5).
  foldLeft( list.take(5).sortWith(_._2 > _._2) )(
    (l, e) => if (e._2 < l.head._2)
                (e :: l.tail).sortWith(_._2 > _._2)
              else
                l
  ).
  sortBy(_._2)
// top5: List[(String, Int)] = List((b,2), (f,3), (h,5), (a,5), (e,6))
```

[UPDATE]

Below is a verbose version of the above `top5` value assignment which hopefully makes the `foldLeft` expression look less overwhelming.

```
val initialTop5Sorted = list.take(5).sortWith(_._2 > _._2)

val originalListTail = list.drop(5)

def updateTop5Sorted = ( list: List[(String, Int)], element: (String, Int) ) => {
  if (element._2 < list.head._2)
    (element :: list.tail).sortWith(_._2 > _._2)
  else
    list
}

val top5 = originalListTail.
  foldLeft( initialTop5Sorted )( updateTop5Sorted ).
  sortBy(_._2)
```

Here's signature of [foldLeft](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/05016d9035ab9b1c866bd9f12fdd0491f1ea0cbb/src/library/scala/collection/Traversable.scala#L46) for your reference:

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B
```

Comment: This code feels write-only to me. Any way to avoid foldLeft? Maybe with a loop comprehension?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `for-comprehension` over `fold` since in this use case `foldLeft` enables successive transformations of the `top5` list in an idiomatic fashion with minimal code.  I've expanded the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach:

```
def topNBy[A, B : Ordering](xs: Iterable[A], n: Int, f: A => B): List[A] = {
  val q = new scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[A]()(Ordering.by(f))
  for (x <- xs) {
    q += x
    if (q.size > n) {
      q.dequeue()
    }
  }
  q.dequeueAll.toList.reverse
}
```

`fold` is useful, and worth getting comfortable with, but if you're not creating a new object to act on in each iteration, and just modifying an existing one, it's no better than a for-loop. And I'd prefer relying on `PriorityQueue` to do the sorting rather than rolling your own, especially given it's an efficient O(log n) implementation. Functional purists might balk at this for being more imperative, but to me it's worth it for readability and conciseness. The mutable state is limited to a single local data structure.

You could even put it in an implicit class:

```
implicit class IterableWithTopN[A](xs: Iterable[A]) {
  def topNBy[B : Ordering](n: Int, f: A => B): List[A] = {
    ...
  }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
Sighting.all.topNBy(5, s => haversineDistance(s, ourLocation))
```